# Error on saving entity says attribute reference unknown entity

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

i have created multiple entities having many to one relations when i try to save the user by adding a child book object i am getting an error that the booking's attribute schedule is referencing to an unknown entity. the error is "@OneToOne or @ManyToOne on com.demo.flightmanagement.entity.Booking.schedule references an unknown entity: com.demo.flightmanagement.entity.Schedule"

**this is airport entity**:

```
@Entity
public class Airport {
    
    @Id
    private int id;
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "airport")
    private List<Schedule> schedules = new ArrayList<Schedule>();

}
```

**this is schedule entity**:

```
@Entity
public class Schedule {
    
    @Id
    private int id;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "schedule")
    private List<Booking> bookings = new ArrayList<Booking>();
    
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Airport.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="airport_id")
    private Airport airport;
}
```

**this is user entity**

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String userName;
    private String password;
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "user")
    private List<Booking> bookings = new ArrayList<Booking>();
}
```

**this is booking entity**

```
@Entity
public class Booking {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "schedule_id")
    private Schedule schedule;
}
```

**this is main calling class**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class JwtExamplesApplication {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepo repo;
    
    @PostConstruct
    public void initUsers() {
        User u =  new User(1, "abc", "def");
        Schedule s = new Schedule(22, null);
        Booking b = new Booking (u, s);
        List<Booking> l = new ArrayList<Booking>();
        l.add(b);
        u.setBookings(l);
        repo.save(u);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JwtExamplesApplication.class, args);
    }

 

}
```

**this is user repository for saving**

```
@Repository
public interface UserDao extends JpaRepository<User, BigInteger> {

}
```

Comment: Did you miss @Entity on Airport Entity?

Comment: no it was there in program i forget to put it here

Comment: Your column names of entities are just Id as per class but you are joining with schedule_id and even in other entities. Make sure your column names are correct.

Comment: @JoinColumn is giving name to foreign key